# What is "_csv" in Python?

Tags: python, csv, symbols, built-in

In attempting to read the source code for the `csv.py` file (as a guide to implementing my own `writer` class in another context) I found that much of the functionality in that file is, in turn, imported from something called `_csv`:

```
 from _csv import Error, __version__, writer, reader, register_dialect, \
                  unregister_dialect, get_dialect, list_dialects, \
                  field_size_limit, \
                  QUOTE_MINIMAL, QUOTE_ALL, QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, QUOTE_NONE, \
                  __doc__
```

I cannot find any file with this name on my system (including searching for files with the Hidden attribute set), although I can do `import _csv` from the Python shell.

What is this module and is it possible to read it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`_csv` is the C "backbone" of the `csv` module. Its source is in [`Modules/_csv.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_csv.c). You can find the compiled version of this module from the Python command prompt with:

```
>>> import _csv
>>> _csv
<module '_csv' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_csv.so'>
```

There are no hidden files in the Python source code :)

Comment: More importantly, according to the [Jython docs](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/modules/_csv/_csv.html), it should never be referenced directly. This is why csv.py imports its functionality.

Comment: Thank you.  That also explains why I can't find any reference to a Writer class - the "class" is implemented in C.

Comment: Hmm.  I assume that Modules is part of the Python source distribution and that the resulting object code is linked to the Python executable?  I have neither a Module sub directory nor very much C code in my Python27 directory (just a few files in site-packages).

Comment: @LarryLustig: yes, that's in the source code. See updated answer.

Comment: Running on Windows, I don't see that directory (lib-dynload) or any file with _csv in the name.  Doesn't matter, since I'm looking for Python examples of the Writer pattern.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @LarryLustig: that's the location on my Linux box. If you enter the same statements, you can see where the library is on yours.

Comment: Thanks, I get `<module '_csv' (built-in)>`, which is along the lines of what I was expecting (seeing as I couldn't find the file myself).

Comment: @LarryLustig: ah, excuse me. I thought all Python versions would print the path. But "built-in", in CPython, always means something's implemented in C (or C++, or Fortran).

Comment: @FredFoo: on Windows binary distributions (e.g. Anaconda), **there is no  ./Modules**, so the definitions of the symbols in _csv are very much hidden. If you find | grep the entire tree, you won't see any definitions.

Answer (score 14):

Not to disagree with larsmans answer.

There is an official explanation of the module naming convention in [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> When an extension module written in C or C++ has an accompanying Python module that provides a higher level (e.g. more object oriented) interface, the C/C++ module has a leading underscore (e.g. _socket)

Comment: +1, I didn't know that was in PEP8 (although I was using the convention for my own C extensions).

Answer (score -1):

An answer has already been accepted, but I wanted to add a few details as I had the same question as the OP.

A .csv file's content is just a comma separated document with values:

```
first,last
john,doe
...
```

You can test this by opening up a .csv file in notepad

If you want to create a .csv file you can write to it and you will get the csv file that you want.

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write('first,last\n')
    file.write('John,Doe\n')
```

Simple solution if you want to write to a .csv file without using "import csv".

Comment: This is not related to the question, which is about a particular built-in module in Python and not in any way about the contents of a file with a `csv1` extension.   It's also, at the very least, quite incomplete as it doesn't discuss the issue of embedded commas and quoting which is central to csv processing.

Comment: @LarryLustig You are right, you ask a question and my answer doesn't answer the question that was asked. But reading the question, the overall goal was to write your own "writer". I stumbled upon this thread because I was searching for the same thing, then realized how easy it is to implement. So I posted to give that example to anyone else who finds this thread. Also I give a very basic example, and there is no issue with embedding commas the way I did; that is beyond the point.